# How to reopen a closed file in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

In vim, is it possible to reopen a closed file in `vi`?  I sometimes am editting files, and I opened them using `:vsplit` or `:split`, and then I accidentally closed one prematuraly.  then I don't want to exit everything so that I have to set upthe window splits all over again.  Is there a way to just return to the previous window setup?  Like, the previous `:split` `vsplit` configuration?

thjanks.